# Выполнение пачки консольных команд средствами Delphi

Tags: delphi, cmd

Есть некоторая последовательность команд, запускаю ее через WinExec:

```
WinExec('cmd /c cd C:\Program Files\Download Master && dmaster.exe D:\outfile.txt ',
  SW_Hide);
```

Но, к сожалению, команды не отрабатывают - ошибки нет, просто ничего не происходит.

Копирую эту же строку и вставляю в новый проект (File - New - VCL Form Application, просто добавляю одну кнопку и вешаю туда эту строчку), все работает. Не знаю имеет ли это значение, но сам проект я запускаю с диска D, а новый проект создал на Рабочем столе (диск C)). Где может быть загвоздка?

Comment: Путь с пробелами надо брать в кавычки "

Comment: @Kromster С двойными кавычками?                                    
  `WinExec(PAnsiChar
    ('cmd /c cd "C:\Program Files\Download Master" && dmaster.exe ' + '"' +
    GetCurrentDir + '"' + '\outfile.txt '), SW_Hide);` Так правильнее?

Comment: Запустил exe-шник с правами администратора, к сожалению, тоже ничего

Comment: Надо не так `'"' + GetCurrentDir + '"' + '\outfile.txt `, а так `'"' + GetCurrentDir + '\outfile.txt' + '"' `. Весь путь должен браться в кавычки

Answer (score 1):

Видите, как важно правильно описать проблему.

> проект я запускаю с диска D, а новый проект создал на Рабочем...

Драйв надо сменить первой командой:

```
WinExec('cmd /c c: && cd "C:\Program Files\Download Master" && dmaster.exe D:\outfile.txt ',
  SW_Hide);
```

или `cd /d`:

```
s := 'cmd /c cd /d "C:\Program Files\Download Master" && dmaster.exe "' +
  GetCurrentDir + '\outfile.txt"';
WinExec(PAnsiChar(s), SW_Hide);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75237/discussion-on-answer-by-igor------delph).

Comment: зачем вообще было драйв менять? `WinExec('"C:\Program Files\Download Master\dmaster.exe" "D:\outfile.txt"', SW_Hide);` не?

Answer (score 0):

Командная строка (cmd) и смена текущей папки вообще не нужны здесь.

```
WinExec('"C:\Program Files\Download Master\dmaster.exe" "D:\outfile.txt"', SW_Hide);
```

Обратите внимание на то, что двойная кавычка внутри пути должна дублироваться, т.е. экранироваться. По этому кавычки лучше не "приклеивать" самостоятельно, а воспользоваться функцией `AnsiQuotedStr`, которая добавит кавычки по краям и продублирует кавычки внутри строки.

```
uses
  SysUtils;
var
  ProgramName: String;
  Param: String;
begin
  ProgramName:= 'C:\Program Files\Download Master\dmaster.exe';
  ProgramName:= AnsiQuotedStr(ProgramName, '"');

  Param := 'D:\outfile.txt';
  Param := AnsiQuotedStr(Param, '"');

  WinExec(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ProgramName + ' ' + Param)), SW_Hide);
end;
```

В этом месте `PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ProgramName + ' ' + Param))` могут быть вопросы с преобразованием юникодных символов в путях в Ansi.

Comment: Лучше не использовать ключевые слова для имен переменных, а так, ловите +1.

Comment: Вообще-то, код не компилируется. Во-первых, нельзя использовать зарезервированное слово `Program` в качестве имени переменной, во-вторых, функция `WinExec` принимает `PAnsiChar`, а не строку, в-третьих вместо `Params'` должно быть `Param`. Замечу так же, что в юникодной версии Delphi функцию надо вызывать вот так: `WinExec(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(...)), SW_Hide);`. Плюс, надо проверять что она возвращает.

Comment: Я не претендовал на компиляцию этого куска кода. Это просто пример для наглядности. `Params`, да, забыл поправить. Преобразование в `PAnsiChar` нужно делать через `AnsiString`, тут вы тоже правы и компилятор об этом тоже предупреждает. Исправил код. Думаю, что автор вопроса справится с проверкой того, что там вернула функция.